# QcustomPlot doesn't want to plot graphs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qcustomplot

I'm newbie in QCustomPlot and wanted to start the first example of QCustomPlot which is about a basic usage. In the following code: I always have a break point which stops the program when it's about to debug (no errors and building is successfully done)

```
QCustomPlot *customPlot;

QVector<double> x(101), y(101); 
for (int i=0; i<101; ++i) {
  x[i] = i/50.0 - 1; // x goes from -1 to 1
  y[i] = x[i]*x[i]; // let's plot a quadratic function
}
customPlot->addGraph();
customPlot->graph(0)->setData(x, y);
customPlot->xAxis->setLabel("x");
customPlot->yAxis->setLabel("y");
customPlot->xAxis->setRange(-1, 1);
customPlot->yAxis->setRange(0, 1);
customPlot->replot();
```

}

The displayed erroris :

```
Unhandled exception at 0x58e828f1 (QtCored4.dll) in ex4.exe: 0xC0000005: 
Access violation reading location 0x00000050.
```

The break point is in here (QList.h file):

```
inline int size() const { return d->end - d->begin; }
```

Comment: You are not allocating customPlot. Does the QCustomPlot need a lot of memory? I would recommend you to allocate it on the stack "QCustomPlot customPlot" and call functions with customPlot.addGraph(), customPlot.[Function]. Also, if you want to allocate on the heap anyway than I recommend you using a shared_pointer, in Qt you can do it like this "QSharedPointer<QCustomPlot> customPlot(new QCustomPlot());" - it will take care to deallocate the memory by itself.

Comment: I just observed. your "i / 50.0" returns an int, you should do "(double) i / 50.0" if you want a double value returned from this operation.

Comment: @Moraru Thank you. Now the interface works without breakpoints. But!! (always a but ;) nothing is displayed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Zeus_M ,that's the only code I see, I tried to help as much as I can having at my disposal only the code that is posted... Don't really know how to help you with your next problem... Btw, I took a look at QCustomPlot and it asks for a QWidget * parameter which means that it needs a parent to display on. If you have for example in your code "QWidget w" and put all the components on it than QCustomPlot would have to be allocated like this "QCustomPlot customPlot(&w)",or if "QWidget *w = new QWidget()" -> "QCustomPlot customPlot(w)".Usually if a parent is not specified it creates it's own window

Comment: @Lilian A. Moraru: It is not an integer division, since 50.0 (note the .0) is a floating point value, so a floating point division will be performed.

Comment: @DerManu I tested and you are right. On older compilers it wasn't working. Might be that in newer compilers the int division with a double/float was overloaded. If you will try compilers like Turbo C++ and Borland C++, you will see that what I'm saying was actually true. When I started learning C++ I started on them and since then I got used to doing this implicit conversion...

Answer (score -1):

Please try:

```
x[i] = i/50 - 1;
```

It's working fine